# AWS RDS Timezone issue (Jamaica)

Tags: amazon-web-services, timezone, amazon-rds, localtime

We have encountered a problem where we need to use local time zones on application servers and the RDS database (Oracle, MySQL, Postgre). Jamaica uses UTC-5 and never observes DST, while the rest of the Eastern region does observe DST.

e.g. Currently if you see over Google for the current eastern standard time. it will give you 11:50 am while in Jamaica it is 10:50 am.

Eastern Standard Time

Time zone in Jamaica (GMT-5)

there is a limited number of available timezones and none of the available timezones seem to work.

How to deal with this situation?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear where that screenshot was taken from. America/Jamaica is the "right" IANA time zone ID, but I don't know whether that's available or not.

Comment: it is not available. screenshot was taken from AWS console options for RDS timezone setting pages